# PHP7 вставка в MySQl через переменную

Tags: mysql, php7, запись

Перепробовал много вариантов, но не работает. Подскажите, где ошибка:

```
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'admin', '1', 'ecommerce');

    /* проверка соединения */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }
    mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES utf8");

    $insert_product = "INSERT INTO `products` (`product_title`, `product_cat`, `product_brand`, `product_price`, `product_desc`, `product_image`, `product_keywords`) VALUES ('$product_title', '$product_cat', '$product_brand', '$product_price', '$product_desc',  $product_image, '$product_keywords');
    ";
    $con->query("$insert_product");
```

Ошибки не выдаёт, но и не записывает. Переменные типа $product_title - определены.

Вероятно, проблема в последних 2 строках.

Update:

```
echo $insert_product; 

// INSERT INTO products (product_title, product_cat, product_brand, product_price, product_desc, product_image, product_keywords) VALUES ('Самсунг', 'Смарфоны', 'Samsung', '111111', 'еккк', 8.jpg, 'кул');
```

Comment: Что вставлять в скобках после VALUES

Comment: вероятно, проблема в том, что вы ленитесь проверить результаты работы функций, и посмотреть лог, если отображение ошибок у вас отключено.

Comment: Каких функций? Подключение к БД я проверяю.

Comment: *Каких функций?* `$con->query("$insert_product");`. Она, вероятно, даёт ошибку, которую Вы благополучно не видите.

Comment: Ещё раз, "что вставлять" указано в скобках после VALUES

Comment: *"что вставлять" указано в скобках после VALUES* Покажите значение $insert_product. Только не в комментарии, а в тексте вопроса.

Comment: В получившемся тексте запроса у Вас в списке вставляемых значений присутствует значение `8.jpg`. Это означает - поле с именем `jpg` из таблицы с именем `8`. Такой таблицы нет в источнике данных запроса, что и приводит к ошибке.

Comment: Вы хотите загрузить в БД картинку? Тогда там должно быть `LOAD_FILE('X:\\folder\\8.jpg')`. А пользователь должен иметь привилегию FILE. И файл - должен лежать в правильном каталоге (secure_file_priv). И размер его должен быть не больше допустимого (max_allowed_packet). В общем, [LOAD_FILE function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file). И тип поля должен быть правильным, бинарным, и charset/collation тоже, иначе от картинки останутся одни ошмётки.

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert_product = "INSERT INTO `products` (`product_title`, `product_cat`, `product_brand`, `product_price`, `product_desc`, `product_image`, `product_keywords`) VALUES ('$product_title', '$product_cat', '$product_brand', '$product_price', '$product_desc',  $product_image, '$product_keywords');
mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ошибку. Значение $product_image в VALUES стоит без кавычек. Т.е.:

```
VALUES (..., $product_image, ...);
```

А нужно:

```
VALUES ('$product_title', '$product_cat', '$product_brand', '$product_price', '$product_desc',  '$product_image', '$product_keywords');
```